# What and where is this wall?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've seen this wall several times on loading screens, but I don't believe I've heard any lore on it or encountered it in-game.  I do have a few masks that look like they may belong to that wall, but all have come from various separate locations.

What is this wall, where is it, and is it tied to any quests?

Please pardon the cell phone screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is supposed to be Labyrinthian. I have not found it either. But I think it is the entrance where you battle the frost dragon.

Outside the main building of Labyrinthian, you will find another "snow covered building".
[image]

Here you find a skeleton that has the wooden mask. Equipping the wooden mask transports you to [Bromjunaar Sanctuary](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bromjunaar_Sanctuary). You have to equip the mask in the snow covered building only. Anywhere else it does not work.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for making this an answer.  I was able to find it while searching UESP with the information you gave in the comments.  The first screenshot you have is the exact building, and it wasn't very far from the fast-travel point.  Inside, you'll find a skeleton corpse next to the ruins of that wall.  Next to the corpse will be the Wooden Mask and a note.  Good luck.

Comment: Ok, I guess by selling two of the masks I totally screwed it, didn't I...? :/

Answer (score 4):

That looks like the [Dragon Priest Shrine](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Priest_Shrine):

[image]

Spoilers:

> When you collect all the masks, you can use it to obtain the final secret mask, [Konahrik](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Konahrik).

Comment: You copied the image.